# Python threading timer

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following script in python that calls a function every X seconds creating a new thread:

```
def function():
    threading.Timer(X, function).start()
    do_something

function()
```

My question is, what if the function takes 2*X seconds to execute? Since I'm using threading this should not be a problem, right? I will have more "instances" of the function running at the same time but once every one finishes its thread should be destroyed. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function takes 2*X seconds, then you're going to have multiple instances of `function` running concurrently. It's easy to see with an example:

```
import threading
import time

X = 2

def function():
    print("Thread {} starting.".format(threading.current_thread()))
    threading.Timer(X, function).start()
    time.sleep(2*X)
    print("Thread {} done.".format(threading.current_thread()))

function()
```

Output:

```
Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140115183785728)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-1, started 140115158210304)> starting.
Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140115183785728)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-2, started 140115149817600)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-3, started 140115141424896)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-1, started 140115158210304)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-4, started 140115133032192)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-2, started 140115149817600)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-3, started 140115141424896)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-5, started 140115158210304)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-6, started 140115141424896)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-4, started 140115133032192)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-7, started 140115149817600)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-5, started 140115158210304)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-8, started 140115133032192)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-6, started 140115141424896)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-9, started 140115158210304)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-7, started 140115149817600)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-10, started 140115141424896)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-8, started 140115133032192)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-11, started 140115149817600)> starting.
<And on and on forever and ever>
```

As you can see from the output, this is also an infinite loop, so the program will never end.

If it's safe for multiple instances of `function` to run at the same time, then this is fine. If it's not, then you need to protect the not-thread-safe part of `function` with a lock:

```
import threading
import time

X = 2
lock = threading.Lock()

def function():
    with lock:
        print("Thread {} starting.".format(threading.current_thread()))
        threading.Timer(X, function).start()
        time.sleep(2*X)
        print("Thread {} done.".format(threading.current_thread()))

function()
```

Output:

```
Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140619426387712)> starting.
Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140619426387712)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-1, started 140619400812288)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-1, started 140619400812288)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-2, started 140619392419584)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-2, started 140619392419584)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-3, started 140619381606144)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-3, started 140619381606144)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-4, started 140619392419584)> starting.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-4, started 140619392419584)> done.
Thread <_Timer(Thread-5, started 140619381606144)> starting.
```

One final note: because of the Global Interpreter Lock, in CPython only one thread can ever actually execute bytecode at a time. So when you use threads, you're not really improving performance if you're doing CPU-bound tasks, because only one thread is every actually executing at a time. Instead, the OS ends up frequently switching between all the threads, giving each a bit of CPU time. This will generally end up being slower than a single-threaded approach, because of the added overhead of switching between the threads. If you're planning on doing CPU-bound work in each thread, you may want to use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.

Comment: Very good answer thanks. What I want to do in each thread is to read urls from a DB and scrape a web page.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could have 3 active threads running at any given time: one that is just about to end, one that's in the middle of a run, and one that's just been spawned.

```
|-----|
   |-----|
      |-----|
```

In practice, you might end up with a few more:

```
import threading
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import time

def function():
    threading.Timer(X, function).start()
    logger.info('{} active threads'.format(threading.active_count()))
    time.sleep(2*X)


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

X = 3
function()
```

yields

```
[16:12:13 MainThread] 2 active threads
[16:12:16 Thread-1] 3 active threads
[16:12:19 Thread-2] 4 active threads
[16:12:22 Thread-3] 4 active threads
[16:12:25 Thread-4] 5 active threads
[16:12:28 Thread-5] 4 active threads
[16:12:31 Thread-6] 4 active threads
[16:12:34 Thread-7] 4 active threads
[16:12:37 Thread-8] 5 active threads
[16:12:40 Thread-9] 4 active threads
[16:12:43 Thread-10] 5 active threads
[16:12:46 Thread-11] 5 active threads
```

I don't see any inherent problem with this; you just have to be aware of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may run into a race condition if one instance of the function is writing to a resource while another is trying to read that same resource.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)#Disadvantages

Can you setup a test so that you can experiment with the behavior that you are concerned with?